# Lua Nginx value null or no present

Tags: if-statement, nginx, lua, openresty

On my Lua conf, I get an error for each metrics

```
prometheus.lua:710: log_error(): No value passed for upstream_time while logging request
```

I check if the value is nil or empty, but it seems is not enough to resolve.

```
init_worker_by_lua_block {
...
metric_upstream_time = prometheus:histogram( "upstream_time", "Upstream", {"host"} )
...
}

log_by_lua_block {
...
if (not (ngx.var.upstream_response_time == nil or ngx.var.upstream_response_time == '' ))
then  
  metric_upstream_time:observe(tonumber(ngx.var.upstream_response_time), {ngx.var.server_name})
end
...    
}
```

nginx_error.log

```
Jan 25 13:56:41 host nginx: 2022/01/25 13:56:41 [error] 142#142: *106669580 [lua] prometheus.lua:734: log_error(): No value passed for upstream_time while logging request, client: xx.xx.201.231, server: xxxxxx, request: "GET /api/v1/xxxxxx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:20190/api/v1/images/xxxx", host: "xxxxxx", referrer: "xxxxxxx"
```

Comment: In the error message, it says `upstram_time`. Could this be a typo?

Comment: thanks for your replying, is not a typo, upstream_time is written correctly

Comment: Still, in the `if` condition you check for `upstream_response_time`, whereas the error message says `upstream_time`. Could you show the call to the logger which triggers your "log_error"?

Comment: I add nginx_error.log

Comment: I add my nginx lua conf

Comment: "$upstream_connect_time keeps time spent on establishing a connection with the upstream server [...] the time is kept in seconds with millisecond resolution. [...] _Times of several connections are separated by commas and colons_" — is it (serveral connections) your case?

Comment: yes it is my case

Comment: Any helps please :(